# JQuery getJSON causes browser redirect

Tags: jquery, rest, getjson, form-authentication, tomcat8

I have a web application that consists of a RESTFul web service and some webpages.  The webpages use JQuery getJSON to retrieve data from the web service and display it in the page.  Everything works as expected when deploying the application without any security constraints.

When I apply a security constraint to both the web service resources and the web pages I am redirected to the login page. I am able to login successfully and I am redirected to the original url requested however when the getJSON line of code is processed the browser redirects to the web service resource url.  The data is retrieved successfully but I need to stop this redirection and stay at the originally requested url.

EDIT:  Here is the security configuration from the web.xml...

```
<web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>WebPage</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>WebService</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

UPDATE: If the security constraint is removed from the web service resources then everything works as expected and the browser redirection does not occur so the issue seems to be related to securing the web service.

Comment: "a security constraint" is rather vague.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just posted the relevant section from the web.xml.